# NextJs `getServerSideProps` is never executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I know that `getServerSideProps` can only be implemented in pages and not in components. And here I already implemented it in the `src/app/posts/[id]/page.tsx` file, but never executed though.

##### `src/app/posts/[id]/page.tsx` file:

```js
import MainLayout from "@kocheng/components/layout/MainLayout";
import SinglePost from "@kocheng/components/SinglePost";
import { FC } from "react";
import { Post } from "@kocheng/dummy-data/Post";
import { GetServerSidePropsContext, PreviewData } from "next";
import { httpAPI } from "@kocheng/lib/axios";
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from "querystring";

type SinglePostPageProps = {
  params: { id: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
  post?: Post;
}

const SinglePostPage: FC<SinglePostPageProps> = ({
  params,
  searchParams,
  post,
}) => {
  console.log({ post }) // always undefined
  
  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div className="container py-4 px-32 flex flex-col items-center">
        {!post ? (
          <h1 className="text-5xl">404 - NOT FOUND</h1>
        ) : (
          <SinglePost post={post}/>
        )}
      </div>
    </MainLayout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>
) {
  const id = parseInt(context.params?.id as string) || 1;
  console.log("Fetching data") // never printed in the server console/terminal
  const post = await httpAPI.get(`/posts/${id}`).then(({ data: res }) => {
    const { data }: { data: Post } = res;
    return data
  });
  console.log("Data Fetched") // never printed in the server console/terminal
  console.log({ post })
  
  return { props: { post } }
}


export default SinglePostPage;
```

Did I do something wrong? Or is there any other successful alternatives? Thanks

Comment: I just realized that Nextjs 13 server component no longer executing getServerSideProps. The alternative answer could be found in [getServerSideProps from nextjs is never invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76131160/getserversideprops-from-nextjs-is-never-invoked?rq=2)